# Are AMRMClientAsync and AMNMClientAsync thread-safe?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I'm writing yarn applications and I wonder if these interfaces are thread-safe. When I look up their api, I cannot find any message of it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code, I have found that its api is thread-safe since it has synchronized symbol.